# Qual melhor maneira de sincronizar dados app desktop com webapi?

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-web-api

Tenho minha aplicação desktop que precisa enviar dados (só enviar) para uma webapi, esses dados não pode-se enviar repetivamente e também após enviado, não enviar novamente, a app desktop será em .net(wpf) a webapi também asp.net webapi.

A aplicação desktop estará em uma máquina com internet precária, então pode haver falha de envio a todo momento, conexão totalmente instavel.

Existe alguma biblioteca que me auxilie nessa sincronização? Lembrando que é apenas de envio(após enviado, não enviar mais).

Comment: @Tmc sua edição altera o sentido da pergunta, não remova comentarios do autor, a menos que estes sejam irrelevantes para a pergunta. E não foi este o caso.

Answer (score 3):

Uma biblioteca, não sei se existe. Mas é fácil contornar isso.

Você terá que criar um identificador (caso já não exista) e uma propriedade para saber se já foi enviado. Quando você enviar um item, é só verificar se já não foi sincronizado. Senão foi enviado, envie, se der tudo certo, altere a propriedade informando que o item já foi enviado.

```
public class ObjetoSincronizado
{
    public ObjetoSincronizado()
    {
        this.SyncId = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Guid SyncId { get; set; }

    public bool Sincronizado { get; set; }
}
```

Do lado da API, sempre que você receber um objeto, verifique se o mesmo já não existe pelo identificador, no caso acima, a propriedade SyncId, se ele já existir, você ignora a informação. Assim não haverá problema se receber duas vezes o mesmo item.